# Invalid Caller IP in Google Cloud Endpoints based API

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints-v2

Started seeing this exception in the logs for Google Cloud Endpoints based API recently even though we haven't changed any code.

The call still goes thru but we see this exception even when the HTTP Status returned for the request is 200.

The API is being called from both other systems as well as mobile apps, some with and some without JWT using custom claims, but seeing the error on all types of requests.

Any idea why we are seeing this and how we can get rid of this problem?

```
com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 400 { 
"error": { 
  "code": 400, 
  "message": "Check request for service \u003credacted_3rd_party_service\u003e has invalid caller_ip value [2405:201:400e:205e:a050:3701:44a:dff8]", 
  "errors": [ { 
    "message": "Check request for service \u003credacted_3rd_party_service\u003e has invalid caller_ip value: [2405:201:400e:205e:a050:3701:44a:dff8]", 
    "domain": "global", 
    "reason": "badRequest" } ], 
  "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT" } }
```

Stacktrace

```
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse (AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute (HttpRequest.java:1067)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed (AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed (AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute (AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
at com.google.api.control.Client.check (Client.java:205)
at com.google.api.control.ControlFilter.doFilter (ControlFilter.java:249)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter (FilterHolder.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter (ServletHandler.java:1601)
at com.google.api.control.ConfigFilter.doFilter (ConfigFilter.java:127)
...
```

Using the following versions of the relevant libraries

```
    appengine-api-1.0-sdk 1.9.86
    endpoints-framework 2.2.2
    endpoints-management-control-appengine 1.0.14
    endpoints-framework-auth 1.0.14
```

Comment: Seeing the same errors. It appears only requests coming from an IPv6 address have this error. All requests coming from an IPv4 address are fine. Is that the case for your project as well?

Comment: More info: the failing check is part of the Endpoints API management tools (https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/adding-api-management) that provide monitoring and integration with the Endpoints page in Cloud console.

Comment: Also reported this to the Endpoints API management library in case it is not meeting a new requirement: https://github.com/cloudendpoints/endpoints-management-java/issues/66

Comment: It appears it was an API issue. No further reports since around 2021-09-10.